# Updating Chartjs Line chart from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

I have a dropdown pre-populated with a list of servers. When I select one and submit the form, I can retrieve an array of the last 12 values of cpu load avg from the mysql db.

Using this data, I'd like to update the the simple line chart below:

```
<div> 
    <canvas id="cpuload" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<script>

    $(function() {

        var cpudata = {

            labels: ["t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11"],
            datasets: [{

                fillColor : "rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.4)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(3, 169, 244, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(3, 169, 244, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [6,2,5,7,9,25,12,5,6,7,17,9]

            }]  
        }

        var ctx = $("#cpuload").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(cpudata, {
            bezierCurve: false
        });


    });
```

I've looked through the Chartjs documentation and noticed a .update() function that would allow updating just the y-values.

I'm stuck in trying to figure out the best way to access the result_array values (some way in a foreach loop?) and assign them to each of the myChart.datasets[0].points[i].value (where i=0-11), and then run update() so that the chart renders with the new values?

Guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more straight forward solution (to me at least):

In your `draw_chart` method (or whatever you're calling to draw the chart):

```
if (typeof chart != 'undefined')
    chart.destroy();
```

Destroy the existing chart if there is one.

From there, just add your data sets, and draw it.

This solution works well in both 1.x and 2.0.